# ElasticSearch - How to match all subwords when querying

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How to write query to match whole sub words in a statement?  Please refer to example below.

E.g.
There are several records existing in ES.

- Record-1   "milk a tea"
- Record-2   "tea table"
- Record-3   "milk hours"

User enters

- Enter "milk", Record-1 and Record-3 show.
- Enter "team", Record-1 and Record-2 show.
- Enter "milk, drink tea", Only Record-1 show.

"milk, drink tea", expected search result from ElasticSearch is that only Record-1("milk a tea").  That is to say, record should be shown only when all sub words are matched.

Comment: `drink` is not present in Record-1. Can you make sure your example correctly reflects your expectation?

Comment: hi @Val, milk/drink/tea are the key words after analyzing(word) by ES, what I expected(user requirement) is that user wants to get the products which product description contains both "milk" and "tea". Maybe, my understanding for ES is wrong?

Comment: So you mean only when all sub words from the document (i.e. both `milk` + `tea`) are matched by any of the query terms?

Comment: @Val, yes. Is that possible? Maybe, this is more clear. If user enters milk, Record 1 and 3 show. If user enters tea, Record 1and 2 show. If user enters milk and tea(milk, drink tea), Only Record 1 show.

Comment: @LeyAng this last example is easy to solve adding `"operator": "and"` to your match query. I believe that what you actually want is this: Record-4 "milk tea biscuits" should NOT match for query "milk tea". Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer for it and hope this could help someone else.

Use "phrase and slop". Below is an Java example

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = 
            QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("milk, drink tea", "function")
                .slop(100).type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE);
```

Answer (score -1):

im not sure if this solution exacly fits you but please:
It will return all records which contains all mentioned words, separated with space:

**here we start with cleaning before creating new function:**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[elasticClasues]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[elasticClasues]
go
```

**The function**

For @data and each word in @tags function will create clause: @data like '%tag%'

example:

@data = 'desc'

@tags = 'big white expensive'

return: desc like '%big%' and desc like '%white%' and desc like '%expensive%'

```
create function [dbo].[elasticClasues] (@what varchar(30), @tags nvarchar(1000) ) returns nvarchar(1000) as
begin
    declare @i int, @out varchar(1000)
    set @i = 0
    set @out = ''
    if @tags='' return '1=1'
    while (LEN(@tags) > 0)
    begin
        select @i = COALESCE( PATINDEX('% %',@tags ), 0)
        if @i = 0
        begin
            select @out = @out + ' ' + @what + ' like ''%' + @tags + '%'''
            return @out
        end
        else
        begin
            select @out = @out + ' ' + @what + ' like ''%' + substring(@tags, 1, @i-1) + '%'' and '
            select @tags = substring(@tags, @i+1, LEN(@tags))
        end
    end -- while
    return @out
end
go
```

**And how to use it:**

```
CREATE TABLE #USER_TABLE(recordid int NOT NULL IDENTITY, data varchar(255) )
insert into #USER_TABLE (data) values ('milkway tea'),('tea in shop'),('shop way milk'),('big tea')
select * from #USER_TABLE
```

**the USER_TABLE:**

```
recordid    data
-------------------------
1           milkway tea
2           tea in shop
3           shop way milk
4           big tea
```

**Lets look after records:**

**A**

```
declare @command nvarchar(1000)
set @command = 'select * from #USER_TABLE where ' + dbo.elasticClasues('data','milk')
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @command;

recordid    data
-------------------------
1           milkway tea
3           shop way milk
```

**B**

```
declare @command nvarchar(1000)
set @command = 'select * from #USER_TABLE where ' + dbo.elasticClasues('data','tea')
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @command;

recordid    data
-------------------------
1           milkway tea
2           tea in shop
4           big tea
```

**C**

```
declare @command nvarchar(1000)
set @command = 'select * from #USER_TABLE where ' + dbo.elasticClasues('data','tea milk')
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @command;

recordid    data
-------------------------
1           milkway tea
```